# Azure storage emulator is not saving files

Tags: c#, azure-storage-emulator

First of all in my `web.config` I added the code :

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
</appSettings>
```

And I created the Containers and as you can see, it's public :

[image]

And the code to upload. The same code works but with a Azure Account, but not with the Emulator!

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("imagesproducts");

var resultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(Images);
var urlsList = new List<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < resultList.Count; i++)
{
    byte[] singleImage = String.IsNullOrEmpty(resultList[i])? null : System.Convert.FromBase64String(resultList[i]);
    CloudBlockBlob block = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg");

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(singleImage, writable: false))
    {
        await block.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
    }
    urlsList.Add(block.Uri.AbsolutePath);
}
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(urlsList);
```

And I always get a Exception of `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread, but a few findings I had while researching similar issues that might save others time:

1) Make sure the Azure Storage Emulator connection string is parsing out to show the localhost IP endpoints and not the default Azure endpoints.

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1; AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;
BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;
TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;
QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;
```

2) Container names will cause this issue. There are specific naming rules for containers.

> A container name must be a valid DNS name, conforming to the following
>   naming rules:
>
> 1. Container names must start with a letter or number, and can contain
>      only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.
> 2. Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed
>      by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in
>      container names.
> 3. All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
> 4. Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata